# div not retaining CSS attribute on click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function that creates a grid of divs that are generated and sent to a container div when the document loads (or when the user resets it). When one hovers over the divs, they highlight (change color). When the user clicks the highlighted div, it changes to black. For some reason, the div that was black reverts back to the original color when I hover over a different div. I'm puzzled as to why that is. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Here's my jsfiddle example:  https://jsfiddle.net/psyonix/1g9p59bx/79/

```
var d = ("<div class='square'></div>");

function createGrid(numSquares) {
    var area = $('#g_area');
    var squareSize = Math.floor(area.innerWidth() / numSquares);
    for (var i = 0, len = (numSquares * numSquares); i < len; i++) {
        area.append(d);
    }

    $('.square')
        .height(squareSize)
        .width(squareSize)
        .hover(

    function () {
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#C8C8C8'
        });
    })
        .click(

    function () {
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#000000'
        });
    });
}

function resetGrid() {
    $(".square").remove();

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    createGrid(8);

    $("#button").click(function () {
        var numSquares = prompt("Please enter the size");
        resetGrid(numSquares);
        createGrid(numSquares);
    });

});
```

Comment: Because you use the hover function to change the cell colors and don't persist the change on clicking a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you click on a `DIV`, you should maintain a flag that tells you hover function to stop changing colors

```
$('.square')
    .height(squareSize)
    .width(squareSize)
    .hover(

function () {
    if ($(this).data("clicked")) return; //ADDED LINE
    $(this).css({
        'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
    });
}, function () {
    if ($(this).data("clicked")) return; //ADDED LINE
    $(this).css({
        'background-color': '#C8C8C8'
    });
})
    .click(

function () {
    $(this).data("clicked", true); //ADDED LINE
    $(this).css({
        'background-color': '#000000'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that, it helps a ton!

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason, the div that was black reverts back to the original color when I hover over a different div

Not quite. It reverts to the original colour when you leave the current div, because that's what you tell it in the second argument to `$('.square').hover`. You would need to remember that the square was clicked, and build extra logic into the "unhover" function.

Fortunately, there is an easier way: use CSS. Note the very bottom of the CSS definitions.

```js
var d = ("<div class='square'></div>");

function createGrid(numSquares) {
    var area = $('#g_area');
    var squareSize = Math.floor(area.innerWidth() / numSquares);
    for (var i = 0, len = (numSquares * numSquares); i < len; i++) {
        area.append(d);
    }

    $('.square')
        .height(squareSize)
        .width(squareSize)
        .click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
        });
}

function resetGrid() {
    $(".square").remove();

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    createGrid(8);

    $("#button").click(function () {
        var numSquares = prompt("Please enter the size");
        resetGrid(numSquares);
        createGrid(numSquares);
    });

});
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: #252525;
    width: 600px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.inner {
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    position: absolute;
    width: 580px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.knob {
    background-color: #575759;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px;
}
#left_b {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 625px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#button {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 265px;
    margin-top: 640px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#right_b {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 510px;
    margin-top: 625px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#g_area {
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    position: relative;
    width: 580px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.square {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.highlight {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: #C8C8C8;
    outline: 1px;
    outline: solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.square {
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
}
.square:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.square.clicked {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">
                <div id="g_area"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="knob" id="left_b"></div>
            <div id="button">
                <button>RESET</button>
            </div>
            <div class="knob" id="right_b"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That makes sense. I could use CSS, but that's not really what I'm aiming to do here. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

it changed because of hover function.

https://jsfiddle.net/1g9p59bx/82/

```
$('.square')
        .height(squareSize)
        .width(squareSize)
        .hover(

    function () {
       if($(this).hasClass('active'))return;
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
        });
    }, function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('active'))return;
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#C8C8C8'
        });
    })
        .click(

    function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#000000'
        });
    });
```